# Drawing an angle that should not cross over an intermediate line

Tags: tikz-angles, tikz-knots

I want to draw an angle arc using the `angles` tikz library. This arc has to not cross over an intermediate line between its limits. I try to use the `knots` package but it doesn't seem to work well with the angles pics.

**The target** (drawn with the `arc path`)

[image]

I also know that I can use the `double line` option but it is not a solution here because the second vector can also be an intermediate line for an other angle.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=0.5cm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{knots,arrows.meta,angles,quotes}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]


    \draw[thin,shorten <=2mm] (0,0)coordinate(O)--+(1,0)coordinate(x);
    \draw [ultra thick,-Stealth](O)--+(80:1)coordinate(F);

    \begin{knot}[
       %draft mode=crossings,
      clip width=1mm]
      %
      \strand [ultra thick,draw,-Stealth](O)--+(30:1);

       \strand pic[red,draw,-latex,angle radius=1cm,angle eccentricity=1.3,"\(\alpha\)"above left]{angle=x--O--F};

       %\strand[red,-latex] (0.5,0)arc[radius=0.5cm,start angle=0,delta angle=80]node[right=3mm]{\(\alpha\)};
\end{knot}



  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is not clear what you asking for. In comment lines you have own solution (as mentioned @marmot below my deleted answer) for your problem. Apparently a solution  with `angle` library doesn't work since it cant be included in `\strand` macro.

Comment: @zarko I am looking for a solution with the `pic angle` and preferably (but not necessarily)  with the knots package. I have seen a solution that pleased me a lot but unfortunately it has been deleted. If it is your answer  please put it back.

Comment: +1 That's a very nice question. It seems to me that at the moment it is not yet possible to do as you wish. Let's hope that  @LoopSpace *(author of these package)* will answer it.